# How to display top 3 highest amount info for a record from a table?

Tags: powerbi, dax

For one of the tables imported into the PowerBI, I have columns as Company Name, Debit Amount, Credit Amount and Net Amount (Calculated column: Debit Amount- Credit Amount).

Now is it possible to pull the three highest Company Names from the table in terms of having either higher Debit, Credit or Net Amount and display it on a tile? May be by creating a measure using DAX or OOTB? It should look like:

```
Top Grossing             Second Grossing       Third Grossing 
12000(Net Amount)        10000(Net Amount)     5000 (Net Amount)
Company Name             Company Name          Company Name
```

I am envisioning the above in terms of tiles and they would change dynamically once anything updates in the data source table. Not sure if this is possible to do using DAX, I am open to suggestions. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAX has a [`TOPN()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492198.aspx) function that you can use for this sort of thing.

The other possibility is to use the built-in advanced filtering. Under the visual level filters, choose filter type Top N, pick how many you want to show and what value you are sorting by.

[image: Top N filter]

Comment: please see the question description, I added a photo. I did as per what you suggested using the TOP N OOTB. I do get results sorted but not the top 3 are being displayed. Main Account Segment is a category which has Debit Amount identical to each main account segment number like 1015, 1145 and so on. I just want to display the top 3 and top 5 Debit Amount record specific to Main Account segment. So only top 3 main account segment should be listed based on the debit amount value.